# Partial not rendering after Ajax request even though it shows in the console as rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a partial but it won't show even though console shows it rendered.

**console output after clicking link**

```
Started GET "/deals/slider" for ::1 at 2022-10-05 16:57:01 -0400
Processing by DealsController#slider as JS
  Rendering deals/slider.js.erb
  Rendered deals/_slider.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 117)
  Rendered deals/slider.js.erb (Duration: 3.1ms | Allocations: 424)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 854)
```

**routes.rb**

```
  root "deals#index"
  get "/auth/:provider/callback", to: "sessions#create"
  delete "sign_out", to: "sessions#destroy"
  get "deals/slider", to: "deals#slider"
  resources :deals, only: [:index, :show, :create] 
  resources :dogs, only: [:index, :show, :create]
```

**index.html.erb**

```
Show deals
<%= link_to "slider", '/deals/slider', remote: true %>
<div id = "testDeals">
</div>
```

**deals_controller.rb**

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @deals = Deal.order(flight_price: :ASC).all
        render :index
    end
    def slider
        city = "LAS"
        @deals_test = Deal.where(origin_city: city)
        respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render layout: false} 
        end        
    end
end
```

**slider.js.erb**

```
$('#testDeals').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "deals/slider")) %>');
```

**_slider.html.erb**

```
<h1>>
YELLO
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours, I realized my simple mistake. Everything was correct but my path for the partial in slider.js.erb

Since I'm going through the deals controller, I'm already looking in the deals views folder. Path should be slider (for _slider.html.erb) and not "deals/slider"

```
$('#testDeals').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "slider")) %>');
```